# How to set cookies to switch style sheets when a link is clicked and set it till another particular link is clicked?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, cookies, responsive

I have a very old site.
Now I want to make it responsive without changing the theme an it's style sheet.

Requirements:

1. Can not change the theme.
2. Can not create child theme.
3. By default, the site should be loaded as non responsive when we
   visit.
4. When a 'switcher link` is clicked whole site should be responsive.
5. When another 'switcher link` is clicked site should be loaded as
   default (Non-responsive)

So I have decided to

1. `enqueue` a separate style sheet when a `switcher link` is clicked.
   : Link to make the site responsive
2. `enqueue` the default style sheet when another `switcher link` is
   clicked. : Link to switch back to default non-responsive site.

Then I've put following two links into my `header.php`

```
<a href="?site=mobile" class="mobile_site" id="mobile_site"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/dza06h.jpg" alt="switch to mobile site"></a>
<a href="?site=desktop" class="desktop_site"><img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/2iu3vl.jpg" alt="switch to desktop site"></a>
```

I put follwoing code into my `functions.php`

```
$site=$_GET['site'];

if ($site == 'mobile'){
    function responsive_css(){
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'wpa_custom',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css'
        );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_css', 999 );
}

if ($site == 'desktop'){
    function default_css(){
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'default_css',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
        );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999 );
}
```

and I added a folder called `css` into my template directory which contains `responsive.css`.

and then

1. when I click the `mobile link` (`class=mobile_site`) the whole site
   becomes responsive. The site link becomes `www.mysite.com/?site=mobile`
2. when I click the `desktop link` (`class=desktop_site`) the whole
   site becomes non-responsive (default site is loaded with it's default
   `style.css`). The site link becomes `www.mysite.com/?site=desktop`

VOILA....!!!!

BUT THE ISSUE IS:

**After I clicked the mobile link if I visit to other pages / posts the whole site becomes Non-responsive. It is responsive if I am in home page only (After I clicked the mobile link)**

For other pages and post I have to click the `mobile link` AGAIN to make it responsive.
In summary, users have to click the `mobile link` every time when they visit to a (new) posts / pages if they want the responsive site.

I've realized the issue is `I did not set a cookie` when the `mobile link` or `desktop link` is clicked.

I referred PHP cookies and some other tutorials but could not get it work.

Now the requirements are (with the above mentioned 5 ) :

6. the site should be remained responsive after the `mobile link (class="mobile_site")` is clicked till the `desktop link(class="desktop_site")` is clicked again.
7. cookies need to be deleted when the tab/browser is closed.

How can I do it using PHP?

*** PLEASE do not just **down vote** and say it's more related to PHP and ask in `stack overflow` . It's mixed and I ask it here. Rather than just down vote do suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **init** action to set  cookie, and other init action to read it. However due its a cookie... you will need also to check GET variable.

```
add_action('init', 'is_it_mobile_or_desktop', 1);

function is_it_mobile_or_desktop(){
    if (isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')) ) {
        setcookie( 'site', $_GET['site'], time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
    }
}

add_action('init', 'who_am_i', 2);
function who_am_i(){

    $site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')) ?  $_GET['site']
            : (isset($_COOKIE['site']) && in_array($_COOKIE['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop'))  ? $_COOKIE['site'] : 'default_case');

    if ($site == 'mobile'){
        function responsive_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'wpa_custom',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css'
            );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'responsive_css', 999 );
    } else {
        function default_css(){
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'default_css',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
            );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'default_css', 999 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @oleg
there are some small syntax errors in you code part `$site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop') ?  $_GET['site']: isset($_COOKIE['site]) &&  && in_array($_COOKIE['site], array('mobile', 'desktop')  ? $_COOKIE['site] : 'default_case');`
**So I have change it to** `$site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop') ?  $_GET['site'] : (isset($_COOKIE['site']) && in_array($_COOKIE['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')  ? $_COOKIE['site'] : 'default_case');` But still **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'**

Comment: check the response again.

Comment: still says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /mysite.com/wp-content/themes/magazine/functions.php on line 1581"
the `line 1581` is: **`$site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop') ?  $_GET['site'] : (isset($_COOKIE['site']) && in_array($_COOKIE['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')  ? $_COOKIE['site'] : 'default_case');`**

Comment: here is the code screen shot : http://i61.tinypic.com/2hf2sqw.jpg

Comment: sorry man - i thought i fix it.

Comment: It's ok.. I found it.. now it works after I've changed it to : `$site = isset($_GET['site']) && in_array($_GET['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop')) ?  $_GET['site'] : (isset($_COOKIE['site']) && in_array($_COOKIE['site'], array('mobile', 'desktop'))  ? $_COOKIE['site'] : 'default_case');`
Anyhow cookie is not saved as per requirement I think.. because hen I am in mobile site if I visit to a inner page it loads in desktop site (loads default style.css).